# Is it possible for an infinite field that does not contain a subfield isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $F$ is a field, then $\text{char}F=0$ or $p$, a prime. If $\text{char}F=0$, we know that it contains a subfield which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. However, there exists field that is infinite and its char. is $p$. So it induce the following question : is it possible for an *infinite* field that does not contain a subfield isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: The answer is yes: indeed if $A$ is a subfield of $B$, then $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic. Thus, an infinite field of characteristic $p$ does not contain $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Crostul Wow, I haven't heard this property before, it seems very useful. I'm going to remember it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. *No* infinite field with characteristice $p$ has a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$. Take, for instance $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$, for any prime $p$.

Comment: Excuse me, what is $\Bbb F_p$?

Comment: @Eric $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the field with $p$ elements.

Comment: Does it stands for nonparticular field? It's my first time seeing this symbol.

Comment: @Eric No. The symbol $\mathbb F$ stands for an arbitrary field. The expression $\mathbb{F}_p$ stands for the only (up to isomorphism) field with characteristic $p$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Eric I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Another example of an infinite field with characteristic $p>0$ is
$$\mathbb{F}_p^a=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$$ the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$.

See article [INFINITE RINGS AND FIELDS WITH POSITIVE CHARACTERISTIC](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/infinite-rings-and-fields-with-positive-characteristic/) for more details.